# JavaScript Regex to count white spaces but not tabs or carriage returns

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to count the amount of spaces I have in string however my RegEx pattern seems to include tabs and carriage returns. How can I correct my code below to only count spaces (I don't want to use " " in my pattern.

```
"This is a string from a textarea on a form... . . ".match(/\s/g).length
```

Comment: What answer do u expect and what are you getting

Comment: Try `str.match(/ /g).length`

Comment: How many spaces are there for `This   is  a string` if there are multiple spaces between words. Do you want to count words only?

Comment: I am actually only wanting to count words yes

Comment: `I don't want to use " " in my pattern`. May I ask why?

Comment: It just feels wrong I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am actually only wanting to count words yes

you can try `\w+`

for example:

```
console.log("This is a".match(/\w+/g).length);
```

---

you can use `\s+` or `[ ]+` to split based on one or more spaces.

Note: Make sure  `\s` matches any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
"This is a string from a textarea on a form... . . ".match(/\u0020/g).length
```

`\u0020` is unicode for a space.

Comment: You can also use `\x20`, no need to use unicode here.

Comment: What would be the reason to prefer `\x20` instead of `\u0020`?